# how to disable Windows shortcuts using java?

Tags: java, windows, jsf

Am developing an online examination system using the jsf framework. My requirement is that the candidate should not be able to use the windows shortcuts like alt+f4, alt+tab, window key and come out of the system. Once he starts the test he should finish. Is there any way to disable these shortcuts? Like running a batch or. Something?

Comment: It is not possible to prevent a prevent a user from being able to close a web browser.

Comment: Write a message "Pressing ALT+F4 will result in severe punishment like horse whipping."

Comment: Rakesh: I almost fell from my chair:D

Comment: @Rakesh nice try better luck next time. If you cannot help please don't interfere.

Comment: @dnivra I am sorry, but I think Rakeshs asnwer is the only one we can give you because I believe that it's not possible to supress this behavior in the browser...

Comment: Yeah, Java can only control itself (the applet), it can't control the browser's behavior. You're out of luck unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible.

You should look for an alternate approach. Register in the DB when an user starts the test. Register in DB when an user finishes the test. On every start of the test, check the registration in DB. If there's an entry indicating that the test has started, but nowhere an entry indicating that the particular test has finished, then handle accordingly. Show an error message telling the user that s/he did it wrong previous time and that s/he should contact the admin, etc.